# Highest value for each GROUP

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns (there are more but these are the important ones) `timestamp` and `analysisId`. There is no constraint on either but in practice timestamp will be unique. Many rows have the same `analysisId` and different `timestamps`. I need a query that returns only the highest `timestamp` for each `analysisId`

So for example the data may look something like

```sql
timestamp | analysisId
1234      | 1
1236      | 1
1300      | 2
1337      | 3
1400      | 3
```

And the result I would want would be

```sql
timestamp | analysisId
1236      | 1
1300      | 2
1400      | 3
```

Currently, I have

`SELECT "timestamp", analysisId FROM myData GROUP BY (analysisId, "timestamp") ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC LIMIT 1;`

However of course this only gives me one result, whereas I want each result per `analysisId`

Comment: If you want one row per analysisId, simply `GROUP BY analysisId`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: And use `MAX()` to get the highest values.

Comment: Why `LIMIT 1`? Skip LIMIT as you want several rows returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple aggregate using *max*

```
select analysisId, max(Timestamp) as Timestamp
from t
group by AnalysisId;
```